# getting 'Could not find or load main class' after adding provided spark .jar dependencies to gradle build

Tags: java, apache-spark, gradle, jar, executable

I am trying to create an executable .jar with some provided dependencies, and I have a
simple example created from 'gradle init' in which I can execute the .jar before adding
a couple of provided dependencies, but where it fails once I add those.

I can reproduce as follows:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
run 'gradle init'

Select type of project to generate:
      2: application

Select implementation language:
      3: Java

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy

Select test framework:
  1: JUnit 4

Project name (default: foo):
Source package (default: foo):
```

Then at the end of build.gradle add the following:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "foo.App"
    }
    zip64 = true
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

At the command line, run:

```
gradle clean ; gradle jar ; java -jar  build/libs/foo.jar
```

And you should see:

```
Hello world.
```

Now change the 'dependencies block in build.gradle to the following:

```
configurations {
        provided
        compile.extendsFrom(provided)
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.4"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.4"
}
```

At the command line, run again:

```
gradle clean ; gradle jar ; java -jar  build/libs/foo.jar
```

And you should see all is good:

```
Hello world.
```

Next, please replace

```
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.4"
    implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.4"
```

with

```
    provided "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.4"
    provided "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.4"
```

At the command line, run again:

```
gradle clean ; gradle jar ; java -jar  build/libs/foo.jar
```

This time you will get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class foo.App
```

So this is clearly due to trying to make the Spark related dependencies 'provided' and therefore
not part of the .jar.  However, you will note that the class foo.App is braindead simple and has
nothing to do with Spark.  So, currently am very confused why the main class suddenly becomes
unfindable when adding these types of dependencies.  Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: if you use provided it requires the specified jars to be on your classpath for you to compile the code. That is the reason you might be getting this error. Error seems to be misleading but that could be the root cause. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731084/provided-dependency-in-gradle

Answer (score 1):

You’ve probably noticed it yourself (and it’s probably also what you intended): the built JAR file contains the entire contents from all dependency JARs when you use `provided` (or `compile`) rather than `implementation` in the `dependencies` block.

The issue here is that your `jar` task configuration really takes *everything* from the dependency JARs, incl. their `META-INF/` directory files. Some of these dependency JARs seem to be signed and thus contain digital signatures in their `META-INF/` directories – which are copied by your `jar` task, too. When running `java -jar …`, these signatures get in the way and result in the class not found error (even though the class *is* in the JAR).

A simple workaround would be to exclude the signatures when creating your JAR file:

```
jar {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

<sub>Credits go to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45153151/1797912).</sub>

Comment: cool !   i got things working w/ shadowJar plugin. But i will accept your answer for sure once i verify it works for me.  Very interesting.. who would have thought to 'exclude'.  Not me !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that combines Chriki's solution w/ the shadowJar approach that also worked for me.  Take your pick !    Please upvote Chriki's answer if this post helped you.

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'

    // This was what I used in my solution
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
        provided
        compile.extendsFrom(provided)
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    provided "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.4.4"
    provided "org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.4"
}


application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = 'foo.App'
}

test {
    // Use junit platform for unit tests
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    // Line below does the trick if you are using 'gradlew jar' 
    // Shout out / big ups to: Chriki
    // Note: My solution (using shadow gradle plugin) 
    // does not require this, but it doesn't hurt
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'            
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "foo.App"
    }
    zip64 = true
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

// This was the second part of what I used in my solution 
// When building, specify: 'gradlew shadowJar' - the jar you want has -all* in it.
// Run with: java -jar  build/libs/foo-all.jar
shadowJar {
    zip64 = true        // I had to specify this twice.. OK.. not gonna lose sleep.
}
```